# Komma nach einem mit „auch“ eingeführten Zusatz im rechten Außenfeld und vor „und“

Tags: comma, parenthesis

Betrachten wir die folgenden Sätze:

> Hunde werden an unterschiedlich langen Leinen ausgeführt, auch auf unterschiedlichen Wiesen(,) und haben trotzdem eins gemeinsam. Alle Hunde freuen sich eines Spaziergangs.

Ist ein Komma nach „Wiesen“ Pflicht, verboten oder optional? Im letzten Fall: Ändert sich die Bedeutung?

Unabhängig davon eine Frage zur Terminologie: Steht eigentlich „auch auf unterschiedlichen Wiesen“ im rechten Außenfeld (wie ich denke, aber nicht gut begründen kann) oder im Nachfeld zu „Hunde werden an unterschiedlich langen Leinen ausgeführt“?

Bitte Erklärungen, durch Regeln unterstützt, mitangeben.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde es mal als „Beisatz“ einordnen, der mit Kommas abgetrennt werden sollte. Also *Pflicht*.

Siehe z. B. Regel 7 hier bei [sofatutor](https://magazin.sofatutor.com/schueler/kommaregeln-einfach-erklaert-so-setzt-du-jedes-komma-richtig/)

Ohne das Komma wird der Satz schwierig lesbar; das allein wäre schon ein Grund fürs Komma. Andererseits könnte man den Satz natürlich auch andersherum aufziehen, um das Problem zu vermeiden. Oft deuten Komma-Probleme auf einen schlecht aufgebauten Satz hin.

Comment: Auch wenn ich die Erklärung für falsch halte: +1 für *Oft deuten Komma-Probleme auf einen schlecht aufgebauten Satz hin.*

Answer (score 0):

optional, keine andere Bedeutung. Aber statt Punkt am "eins gemeinsam." sollte man Doppelpunkt machen "eins gemeinsam:".

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt einen Zusammenhang zwischen "Beisatz" und "Einschub" bei subjektlosem "und"-Satz:

> Ich hoffe, dass er bald kommt und mir hilft.

*Er* kommt und hilft.

> Ich hoffe, dass er bald kommt, und gebe nicht auf.

*Ich* hoffe und gebe nicht auf

Hier schliesst das Komma nur den "dass"-Teilsatz ab. Normalerweise würde man zum Ausbalancieren das Subjekt ergänzen:

> Ich hoffe, dass er bald kommt, und ***ich*** gebe nicht auf.

In der Frage wird genau das künstlich vermieden:

> *...eins gemeinsam. Alle Hunde freuen sich...*

---

> Du auch!
>
> Du, auch!

Es kommt zwar logisch auf desselbe raus, psychologisch aber nicht. Während auf Caesar "Du auch" passt (es war ja mehr Bestätigung als Überraschung) , drückt:

> Ich habe Knieschmerzen, auch in der Nacht.

(mit Komma) eher das Gewünschte aus. Eine klare Aussage und ein Zusatz.

> Ich habe auch in der Nacht Knieschmerzen.

Hier ist nicht klar ob das Knie oder der Schlaf das Problem ist - macht je nach Kontext aber Sinn.

---

> Hunde werden an unterschiedlich langen Leinen ausgeführt, auch auf
>   unterschiedlichen Wiesen(,) und haben trotzdem eins gemeinsam. Alle
>   Hunde freuen sich eines Spaziergangs.
>
> Sie werden **an und auf** unterschiedlich langen Leinen und Wiesen
>   ausgeführt, **und sie haben** trotzdem eins gemeinsam: Alle Hunde freuen
>   sich über einen Spaziergang.

(Die Wiesen sind jetzt halt nicht nur uterschiedlich, sondern unterschiedlich lang, aber wenn schon denn schon. Ich habe downgevoted weil der Satz mit Absicht auf die Kommaregeln bis an die Grenzen geht.)